# find extremely slow on CIFS share

Tags: command-line, find, cifs

Entry in `/proc/mounts`:

```
//OUR_ORG.file.core.windows.net/OUR_ORG /data/csv cifs rw,relatime,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp,cache=strict,username=OUR_ORG,domain=,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=SOME_IP,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,soft,persistenthandles,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1 0 0
```

I'm trying to run command:

```
find /data/csv -mtime -1 -name '*.csv.gz'
```

Unfortunely, it's super slow.

```
ls -alh --time-style=+%D /data/csv/
```

This command runs fine and completes in less than 2 seconds.

I checked strace. `find` use `newfstatat` internally, but `ls` use `lstat` internally.

I would prefer to use `find` with some switch rather than parse `ls` output. Can I somehow make `find` command reasonably fast?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar find command that took close to 10mins, while ls command returned in seconds. Cache setting didn't have any effect.

By using parameter `actimeo=60` (default = 1 sec), the find command returned in less than 10 seconds.

> actimeo=arg
>
> The time (in seconds) that the CIFS client caches attributes of a file
> or directory before it requests attribute information from a server.
> During this period the changes that occur on the server remain
> undetected until the client checks the server again. By default, the
> attribute cache timeout is set to 1 second. This means more frequent
> on-the-wire calls to the server to check whether attributes have
> changed which could impact performance. With this option users can
> make a tradeoff between performance and cache metadata correctness,
> depending on workload needs. Shorter timeouts mean better cache
> coherency, but frequent increased number of calls to the server.
> Longer timeouts mean a reduced number of calls to the server but
> looser cache coherency. The actimeo value is a positive integer that
> can hold values between 0 and a maximum value of 2^30 * HZ (frequency
> of timer interrupt) setting.

Answer (score 2):

Change the parameters to

```
cache=loose
```

[With one serious comment from the manual page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-mount.cifs/):

> cache=loose can cause data corruption when multiple readers and writers are working on the same files.

---

```
cache=

Cache mode. See the section below on CACHE COHERENCY for details. Allowed values are:

    • none: do not cache file data at all 

    • strict: follow the CIFS/SMB2 protocol strictly 

    • loose: allow loose caching semantics 

The default in kernels prior to 3.7 was "loose". As of kernel 3.7 the default is "strict".
```

Comment: OP even has `cache=strict` set explicitly.

Comment: It's great answer, but I asked sysadmin if I'm allowed to change this setting. I'm not allowed.